# Cross validation_Do we need to mention it in our publication?

Tags: cross-validation

Do we need to mention we used the cross-validation technique in our statistical section of the publications? If yes, is there any standard format for how to state this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Machine learning papers I read all mentioned how they do cross-validation. Remember to keep it brief. Something like:

> "... In this study we have applied leave-one-out cross validation ... Our cross validation accuracy is 80% ... "

is sufficient.